# Call a JList method from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, object, jlist

The following code is in progress:

```
private final Controller controller = new Controller();
private final XSimpleList lists[] = new XSimpleList[2]; //extends JList (my framework)
```

I have a public class X which extends JFrame and implements Runnable.
This public class X have a defined constructor.
The last line in the constructor is:

```
(new Thread(new X())).start();
```

As required I do have a `public void run() {}`.
In this run() method I do have a

```
lists[0].FillUp(controller.getSomeData(), 2);
```

The thread is programmed to execute the above line when it received a messages from a udp server.
So... the problem is when the given line is executed (runtime).
It results in a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

XSimpleList code segments:

```
final JList hW;
final DefaultListModel dlm;
final JScrollPane lsp;

public final void FillUp(MyTypeRepository volume, int filter) {
    dlm.clear();
    //iterations
    dlm.addElement(some_data);
    //end iterations
}
```

My question is...
How I can solve this issue in order the **lists[0]** not to return that NullPointer when called from the started Thread?

When executed (only) from the class X the issue is not present. I think is a problem with sharing data between 2 "pipes", meaning the parent instance (class x) and the child instance (thread y).

Thank You!

Comment: Did you setup the array `lists` anywhere, i.e. `lists[0] = new XSimpleList()`?

Comment: yes, everything is done right... the only issue is that it throws that nullpointer when the method is called from the thread...

Comment: Whatever the reason is, your design must completely be changed, because Swing components and their model must only be accessed from the event dispatch thread. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading (which is linked from the javadoc of each and every swing component)

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, this should be pretty easy to fix. Just wrap those calls into `invokeLater`/`invokeAndWait`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lists[0] has NULL because
private final XSimpleList lists[] = new XSimpleList[2] creates an array with NULL values Like:
  lists[0] = NULL;
  lists[1] = NULL;

You should write code as:
private final XSimpleList lists[] = new XSimpleList[2];
lists[0] = new XSimpleList();
lists[1] = new XSimpleList();
```

Comment: this is the correct answer to the OP's question (array initialization behavior).  Rhere is a much bigger problem of him trying to interact with a Swing component from a non-EDT thread - but I think the comments cover that well enough.

Comment: the array is initialized as lists[0] = new XSimpleList(); in the constructor. the problem must be related to " trying to interact with a Swing component from a non-EDT thread".